Data Augmentation Scan Order with Multiple Latent Variables
I am trying to extend the traditional definition of the data augmentation algorithm to more than one auxillary variable and with a random scan order.
The Data Augmentation algorithm
Consider a random variable $X$ and another (auxillary) random variable $Y$ with state spaces $\textsf{X}$ and $\textsf{Y}$, respectively, and assume there exists a joint pdf $p:\textsf{X} \times \textsf{Y} \longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $\int_\textsf{Y}p(x, y)\,\mathrm{d}y = p_X(x)$ and $\int_\textsf{X}p(x, y)\,\mathrm{d}x = p_Y(y)$.
If sampling from $p_X$ is intractable, we may generate a Markov chain that samples from the marginal $p_X$ using the conditional densities. Specifically, If the current state of the chain is $X_n = x$, then we may simulate $X_{n+1}$ as follows:

Draw $Y \sim p_{Y|X}(\cdot|x)$, and call the observed value $y$.
Draw $X_{n+1} \sim p_{X|Y}(\cdot|y)$.

This corresponds to a kernel $\kappa(x'|x) = \int_{\textsf{Y}}p_{X|Y}(x'|y)p_{Y|X}(y|x)\,\mathrm{d}y$.
It can be shown that $\kappa$ is a Markov transition density and is invariant (and also reversible) with respect to $p_X$, i.e., $p_X(x') = \int_{\textsf{X}} \kappa(x'|x)p_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.
Extension to $m$ auxillary variables?
Now consider $m$ auxillary variables $Y_1, \ldots, Y_m$ with joint pdf $p:\textsf{X} \times \textsf{Y}_1 \times \cdots\times \textsf{Y}_m \longrightarrow [0,\infty)$, and assume I only have access to the conditional pdfs of one variable given one other variable, i.e, $p_{Y_i|X}, p_{X|Y_i}, p_{Y_j|Y_i}$ for all $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $i\neq j$.
I am interested in characterizing $p_X$ (as well as each $p_{Y_i}$). It's straightfoward to show (I think?) that $p_X$ is invariant to the transition kernel corresponding to a particular scan order through the auxillary variables. Specifically, for the scan order $i\rightarrow j \cdots \rightarrow k \rightarrow l$ we have
\begin{align}
p_{Y_i}(y_i) &= \int_{\textsf{X}} p_{Y_i|X}(y_i|x)p_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,\\
p_{Y_j}(y_j) &= \int_{\textsf{Y}_i} p_{Y_j|Y_i}(y_j|y_i)p_{Y_i}(y_i)\,\mathrm{d}y_i.\\
\cdots\\
p_{Y_l}(y_l) &= \int_{\textsf{Y}_k} p_{Y_l|Y_k}(y_l|y_k)p_{Y_k}(y_k)\,\mathrm{d}y_k.\\
p_{X}(x') &= \int_{\textsf{Y}_l} p_{X|Y_l}(x'|y_l)p_{Y_l}(y_l)\,\mathrm{d}y_l.\\
\end{align}
Thus, the overall transition kernel $\kappa(x'|x) = \int_{\textsf{Y}_l}\int_{\textsf{Y}_k}\cdots\int_{\textsf{Y}_i}p_{X|Y_l}(x'|y_l)p_{Y_l|Y_k}(y_l|y_k)\cdots p_{Y_j|Y_i}(y_j|y_i)p_{Y_i|X}(y_i|x)\,\mathrm{d}y_l\,\mathrm{d}y_k\,\cdots\mathrm{d}y_i$ is invariant and may be used to sample from $p_X$. I've also been able to confirm this on a Gaussian toy example.
Random scan order
However, I'm unsure how to prove invariance of $p_X$ for (uniformly) random scan orders through the auxillary variables. I tried relating my problem to the proof of invariance and reversibility for a random scan order Gibbs Sampler, but I'm not seeing any obvious connections.
I would appreciate any help!
